# Number of overlapping requests for a user in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a `user_id` column and a `start_date` and `end_date` column.

I want to create a new column which finds the number of overlapping start_dates and end_dates for each user at the given time interval.

Is there a way to do this without using a for loop?

example:

```
User         |    Start |         End  | Simultaneous Events


`0  user_x  2013-02-09  2013-02-11   2`   <---- overlaps with row 2

`1  user_x  2013-06-06  2013-06-08   1`

`2  user_x  2013-02-10  2013-02-13   2`

`3  user_y  2014-01-06  2014-01-11   1`

`4  user_x  2014-01-06  2014-01-11   1`
```

Comment: any examples with data?

Comment: @White I added a mock

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking to have a smart algorithm to solve it fast, the following is not to help.

"Without loop", if your intention is to use recursion, the following is not to help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0,'user_x','2013-02-09','2013-02-11'],
    [1,'user_x','2013-06-06','2013-06-08'],
    [2,'user_x','2013-02-10','2013-02-13'],
    [3,'user_y','2014-01-06','2014-01-11'],
    [4,'user_x','2014-01-06','2014-01-11']])

df.columns = ['id','user','start','end']
merge_df = pd.merge(df, df, on=['user'], suffixes=['','_compare'])
merge_df['overlap'] = ((merge_df['start']>=merge_df['start_compare'])&(merge_df['start']<=merge_df['end_compare'])) | ((merge_df['end']>=merge_df['start_compare'])&(merge_df['end']<=merge_df['end_compare']))
result = merge_df[merge_df.overlap>0].groupby(['id','user','start','end']).agg({'id_compare':np.size}).reset_index()
```

result as following

```
   id    user       start         end  id_compare
0   0  user_x  2013-02-09  2013-02-11           2
1   1  user_x  2013-06-06  2013-06-08           1
2   2  user_x  2013-02-10  2013-02-13           2
3   3  user_y  2014-01-06  2014-01-11           1
4   4  user_x  2014-01-06  2014-01-11           1
```

Just a side note, in order to understand this better, I will suggest you to read on sql, it will be helpful. Idea is simple. Matching all rows with the same user id (pd.merge) and decide whether it is an overlap, finally group by user id to count occurrence of overlap ids.